# navigate with id using knockout binding in single page application

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs, durandal, single-page-application

I have an issue with below. please help me on this

```
<a href="#" data-bind="event: { click: navigateManageReturns(OrderNo) }, text: OrderNo">       </a>
```

when ever click: navigateManageReturns is at click event all data is binding in Grid. if i modify to click: navigateManageReturns(OrderNo), data is not binding and showing blank data in grid.

Comment: when you use the `event` or `click` binding, typically you would want to pass a function (`navigateManageReturns`) rather than the invocation of a function (`navigateManageReturns(OrderNo)`) unless the invocation actually returns a function.  Knockout will automatically pass the context as the first argument (and use it as the value of `this`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handler of the click event is probably in the ViewModel, so you should access the parent context to get to that handler:

```
<a href="#" data-bind="event: { click: $parent.navigateManageReturns }, text: OrderNo"></a>
```

Inside the function, you will get the object:

```
 function navigateManageReturns (order){
     var number = order.OrderNo;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" data-bind="event: {click: function(){ navigatemanageReturns(OrderNo)}, text: OrderNo"> </a>
```

This should do the trick

edit: you should also consider what others wrote with:

```
data-bind="event: {click: navigatemanageReturns}"
```

and then catch object passed on. Use `console.log` to see what you need from that object